# Accessing .. under a symlink

Tags: symlink

I have a script that makes an environment using symlinks, and then calls a process that uses `../` to navagate to other parts of that environement. Unfortunately since it uses symlinks .. refers to the true parent and not the owner of the symlink.

My main constraint is that I can't change the script that's using `../`.

Diagram

```
/.../realDirA/
              childScript.sh
      

/.../realDirB/
              someTarget

/tmp/fakeParent/
                fakeA -> realDirA
                fakeB -> realDirB
```

And the `childScript.sh` uses `/tmp/fakeParent/fakeA/../fakeB/someTarget`, and I can't change `childScript.sh` but I have full control over `fakeParent` and what ever permissions I need.

Comment: not clear what the problem is. What is the working directory when `../someTarget` is used? That determines what `..` refers to, not whether something is a symlink or not.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I'm in `/tmp/fakeParent/fakeA`, but I'd expect that `pwd` is then actually `/...realDirA/` so `../` is in the whatever above `realDirA`

Comment: If you `cd /tmp/fakeParent/fakeA` then you are actually in `/.../realDirA`, Are you trying to make `../someTarget` get to `/.../realDirB/someTarget`? If so you probably don't want `fakeA` to be a symbolic link, you want it to be a directory full of symbolic links. As an aside, always worth reading https://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/4th_edition/papers/lexnames

Comment: Thanks, I'll read really quick, I changed the question and the script to still run in /tmp/ but the `..` in that jumps out of my `/tmp` and into the `...` space.

Comment: I don't understand. "I'm in /tmp/fakeParent/fakeA" means "my working directory is /tmp/fakeParent/fakeA"; so `..` refers to /tmp/fakeParent/; simple as that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, remember the shells often keep track of the symlinks in the path the user used to go there, so after `cd /tmp/fakeParent/fakeA`, the shell would show the working directory as `/tmp/fakeParent/fakeA`, and `cd ..` would go to `/tmp/fakeParent/`, while an independent program would be unaware of the symlinks, only see `/whatever/realDirA`, and referring to `..` there would go to `/whatever`